# is generate Static params needed for each nested route?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a quick question about whether or not I need to use generate static params for each nested route. For example, if I have a route /[slug] that I use generateStaticParams, do I need to use generateStaticParams for /[slug]/route1, /[slug]/route1/route2, etc if they only dynamic param in the pathname is [slug]?

Thanks!

Note: Also considering that /[slug]/route1, /[slug]/route1/route2, etc would need access to the same data fetched in /[slug]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for each child route ex: `/[slug]/child1/child2`. You need to use `generateStaticParams` if you want to access the data fetched in the `/[slug]` route. The child routes can access the data fetched via the `params` returned from the parent route.

Further reading [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params#generate-params-from-the-top-down)